# coding with Windows built-in text editors

Tags: windows-7, text-editors

Are there any ways to configure or run any of the built-in Windows 7 text editors to make it easier to write code with? Line numbers, colors, etc.

I'm stuck on a locked down machine which I don't have administrator rights to and I can't install anything. I need to edit some java code, but there are no installed text editors other than the default Windows 7 editors like Notepad and Wordpad. I've been trying to make do with the Powershell ISE.

Alternatively (maybe more realistically), are there any programming text editors anyone knows of which I can run directly from a jar? On this machine I am able to double click jar files and run them.

For example, I saw jEdit, but it requires me to run an install program so that's out.

Comment: Use a portable program?

Comment: Can you open it up in Google Docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any ways to configure or run any of the built-in Windows 7 text editors to make it easier to write code with? Line numbers, colors, etc.

Nope.

> I'm stuck on a locked down machine which I don't have administrator rights to and I can't install anything.

Can you get that machine online? If so, why not use one of the many online code editors ([example](https://www.compilejava.net/))?

Alternatively, you could also use a "portable" editor that doesn't require installing.   For example, [Microsoft's Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) can be downloaded in Zip format which requires no installation.

[image: Code Download Options]

Comment: Notepad++ has a portable option - http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable

Comment: Could not run Microsoft's Code, got UAC prompt to run applications downloaded from internet. But the online editor works. Had not tried an online editor before, cool!  Thanks